# has_many :messages where user is recipient or author in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Message model belongs_to author and recipient.

```
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "recipient_id"
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "author_id"
```

Now what I would like to do is setting up a has_many relationship in the User model that is getting all messages where the user is ether author or recipient in a single query. How do I do something like that?

```
has_many :messages, :finder_sql => ['author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}']
```

However this breaks.

```
  User.first.messages
    User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
    Message Load (0.5ms)  author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}
  PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "author_id"
  LINE 1: author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}
      ^
:author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id} ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:  PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "author_id" LINE 1: author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}
```

**Update**: 
Interpolating variables was removed from Rails 3.1. Now you have to use a proc

```
  has_many :messages, :finder_sql => proc { "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}" }
```

[source](https://gist.github.com/958283)

Comment: Phew! It'd be nice if the Rails docs said somethin' about this, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot interpolate variables in single quotes.

```
'author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}'
```

should be

```
"author_id = #{self.id} or recipient_id = #{self.id}"
```

Comment: See my question for the solution. You have to use a proc in Rails 3.1